# Understanding the nature of Kafka Consumer Rebalance within same consumer-group but with different subscriptions

Tags: apache-kafka

I need some clarifications regarding how re-balancing affects consumers in same group but who are subscribing to different topic regex in Kafka [0.10.1]

Let's say we've three kafka consumers `c1`, `c2` and `c3`. They subscribe to topics `*_t1`, `*_t2` and `*_t3` respectively.
Now, let's put all of these consumers into the same consumer group, say `my-consumer`. In this scenario, would `c2` and `c3` participate in re-balancing, if new topics are added in `*_t1`?

I went through the kafka documentation [here](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/documentation.html#impl_consumerregistration) and found some relevant info. Point #2 clearly says that the consumer:

`Register a watch on changes (new consumers joining or any existing consumers leaving) under the consumer id registry. (Each change triggers rebalancing among all consumers within the group to which the changed consumer belongs.)`

So, re-balancing will happen for `c2` and `c3` even if new consumers join who are subscribing to `*_t1`. But I'm little sketchy about how point #4 affects re-balancing. I think, for topic creation/deletion/alter happening in `*_t1`, `c2` and `c3` won't be affected? Isn't that so?

I understand that we can have three different consumer groups across the consumers, but I'm trying to understand if that's necessary and/or a good practice.

Comment: hope this is helpful - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/131337/can-i-use-same-consumer-group-id-for-two-different.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, re-balancing will happen for c2 and c3 even if new consumers join
>   who are subscribing to *_t1.

That's correct.

> But I'm little sketchy about how point #4
>   affects re-balancing. I think, for topic creation/deletion/alter
>   happening in *_t1, c2 and c3 won't be affected? Isn't that so?

As long as **consumers** are in the **same consumer group**, any changes(like change in number of consumers, for example consumer c1 subscribing to *_t1 topics is stopped) *rebalancing will occur*, even though c2 and c3 have nothing to do with *_t1. This is similar for any change in the number of topics/partitions. This is because for all the consumers in the same consumer group, Kafka would like to make sure that all the partitions(for all subscribed topics) are being taken care of, i.e 1 partition 1 consumer. **Take note, that 1 consumer can consume more than 1 partition, but not vice-versa.**

> I understand that we can have three different consumer groups across
>   the consumers, but I'm trying to understand if that's necessary and/or
>   a good practice.

The recommended practice(**and yes, you are right**) is to put the consumers in the same consumer group IFF they subscribe to the same topics. In your case above, there would be 3 consumer groups, each one consuming from the respective topics.

Consumer group my-consumer-1, with c1 consuming *_t1
Consumer group my-consumer-2, with c2 consuming *_t2
Consumer group my-consumer-3, with c3 consuming *_t3

Any change happening in my-consumer-1, would therefore have no performance impact on group my-consumer-2 and my-consumer-3.

For posterity, the definition of rebalancing taken [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+0.9+Consumer+Rewrite+Design):

> Rebalancing is the process where a group of consumer instances
>   (belonging to the same group) co-ordinate to own a mutually exclusive
>   set of partitions of topics that the group is subscribed to. At the end of a successful rebalance operation for a consumer group, every partition for all subscribed topics will be owned by a single consumer instance within the group. The way rebalancing works is as follows. Every broker is elected as the coordinator for a subset of the consumer groups. The co-ordinator broker for a group is responsible for orchestrating a rebalance operation on consumer group membership changes or partition changes for the subscribed topics. It is also responsible for communicating the resulting partition ownership configuration to all consumers of the group undergoing a rebalance operation.

And some good news, in Kafka 2.5, there might have some "performance" [improvement](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_250_notable) to the "effect" of rebalancing:

> When RebalanceProtocol#COOPERATIVE is used, Consumer#poll can still
>   return data while it is in the middle of a rebalance for those
>   partitions still owned by the consumer; in addition
>   Consumer#commitSync now may throw a non-fatal
>   RebalanceInProgressException to notify users of such an event, in
>   order to distinguish from the fatal CommitFailedException and allow
>   users to complete the ongoing rebalance and then reattempt committing
>   offsets for those still-owned partitions.